# Elements beetween two numbers in c# list using LINQ

Tags: c#, list, linq

I am struggling with one problem. I have this list: 1,1,2,7,9,7,7,7,8,5,5,5,5,5,5,2,1,1,1,1,1. And I need to get somehow the part beetween 2s (2,7,9,7,7,7,8,5,5,5,5,5,5,2). I NEED TO USE LINQ ONLY. I have tried this: `test.SkipWhile(x => x != 2).TakeWhile(x => x != 2).Vypis();`, but this always returns nothing. Vypis() is extension method:

```
static class Rozsireni
{
    public static void Vypis<T>(this IEnumerable<T> a, string textPred = "")
    {
        Console.Write(textPred);
        foreach (T x in a)
            Console.Write("{0}, ", x);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Does somebody has some idea? Thank you for your help and time.
EDIT: The list must contains the 2's aswell.

Comment: You should skip the first 2: `test.SkipWhile(x => x != 2).Skip(1).TakeWhile(x => x != 2);`

Comment: Yes, the answer has it. Not only one 2, all the 2's should be skipped.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to say that I need that 2's as well.

Comment: Try: `test.GetRange(test.IndexOf(2), test.LastIndexOf(2) - 1).Vypis();`

Answer (score 1):

I think you should first skip number that are not equal to 2, then skip numbers that are equal to 2, then again take those that are not equal to 2 and done:

```
test.SkipWhile(x => x != 2).SkipWhile(x => x == 2).TakeWhile(x => x != 2).Vypis();
```

result should be:

`7,9,7,7,7,8,5,5,5,5,5,5`

edit:
you edited your question and noted you need head and tail `2`s. I do not know any single and elegant way to do it. sorry, this maybe look a little ugly:

```
        var data = new int[] { 1, 1, 2, 7, 9, 7, 7, 7, 8, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2,2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };


        var arr1 = data.SkipWhile(x => x != 2).TakeWhile(x => x == 2).ToArray();//select head 2 s
        var arr2 = data.SkipWhile(x => x != 2).SkipWhile(x => x == 2).TakeWhile(x => x != 2).ToArray();//select mids
        var arr3 = data.SkipWhile(x => x != 2).SkipWhile(x => x == 2).SkipWhile(x => x != 2).TakeWhile(x => x == 2).ToArray();//select tail 2s

        var arr = arr1.Concat(arr2).Concat(arr3);//concat them all
```

or in compact form

```
test.SkipWhile(x => x != 2).TakeWhile(x => x == 2).ToArray().Concat(data.SkipWhile(x => x != 2).SkipWhile(x => x == 2).TakeWhile(x => x != 2).ToArray()).Concat(data.SkipWhile(x => x != 2).SkipWhile(x => x == 2).SkipWhile(x => x != 2).TakeWhile(x => x == 2).ToArray());
```

Comment: No, that is the problem. I need to have the 2's in the list too,.

Comment: @JanSmutný i've updated the post, take a check for head and tail `2`s

Comment: I tried, but still no change. It always writes nothing. Did you tried that on your own?

Comment: @JanSmutný Yes, you are right, second approach do not work, I've removed it. I think not possible to just solve your problem with SkipWhile and TakeWhile, but a Concat or Union(). does it matters?

Comment: No, it doesn't. I can use any LINQ I want.

Comment: @JanSmutný i think there is no any pretty way to do it, however i've edited the answer :) sorry solution is somehow ugly

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the array passed to TakeWhile is 2,7,9,7,7,7,8,5,5,5,5,5,5,2,1,1,1,1,1 so it fails on the first check if x != 2.  Even if you were to skip the first 2 with the following it would also skip the 2nd 2.

```
test.SkipWhile(x => x != 2).TakeWhile((x, index) => x != 2 || index == 0).Vypis();
```

So you need to simply use:

```
test.SkipWhile(x => x != 2).TakeWhile(x => x > 1).Vypis();
```

Comment: Ehm... Sure. Thanks. But that will not work, if there will be no 1 after 2. I need universal code, which works for all lists. But thank you very much!